B&W short (1960s?) - soldier buried up to neck in rocks
I'm trying to recall the name of a short film I saw in approx 1971, at a friend's college film society session. It was quite short, maybe 15 minutes. There was no dialogue as far as I recall.
It showed a young man, who I think was an American Civil War soldier, somehow being buried up to his neck in rocks. They are audible scraping over each other until they settle. He is lying on his back; only his head and neck protrude. He is fully conscious. It is clear to us, as it must be to him, that he is doomed if no help comes.
After a while a fly settles on his nose and seems to be contemplating him. It seems likely that he will go mad before he dies.
I have always thought that the film was part of the French New Wave, and that the director was Jean-Luc Godard, but I can't find any such film in his filmography.

It sounds familiar to me. Could it be a The Twilight Zone episode?

@Joachim I don't think so. I won't say definitely not as it was 53 years ago, but  . A black and white 'arthouse' European type movie. Probably French. Not an episode of a TV show.

One of the missing is another short film from an Ambrose Bierce story that has similar themes and kind of fits your description.

The 'rocks' were rubble from a demolished building. He was not lying on his back. The film was, as @Mark correctly suggested in a comment, the 1968 26-minute film One of the Missing by the English director Tony Scott (1944-2012), aged 24 at the time, who went on to direct a number of successful films.

